# CSS to change radio button label

Tags: css, label

Hi I am trying to change the labels on radio buttons within an online survey. New to CSS and have worked out a bit the last few weeks but cannot work this out,

I have tried a range of things (none have worked) using content and display such as

```
#question-2 label:nth-child(5) {
content: "Y";
}
```

and

```
label , #button-rating-2-5 {
content: "Y";
}
```

Below is taken from the survey, i hope this is enough of a guide to help, i can only upload CSS

```
<label title="4" for="button-rating-2-5">
    4
    <input id="button-rating-2-5" type="radio" name="question-2" value="5" style="">
</label>
```

Just tried the following and it inserts "y" in the label

```
#question-2 label:nth-child(5):before {
content: "Y";
font-size: 14px; 
}
```

However if I use any of the following the label AND button is removed not just the label.

```
#question-2 .answer-container{ 
font-size: 0; 
}

#question-2 Label{ 
font-size: 0; 
}

#question-2 label:nth-child(5) {
font-size: 0;
}
```

So in other words I just want to change the default "4" to show "Y" on this question. Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Have not tried with javascript? It would be very simple to replace the number with the letter using javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `visibility` option to elements. An example below:

```css
/* You can use label[for="button-rating-2-5"]{} selector too */
label[title="4"] {
  visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 0 /* no space between :before and input */
}

label[title="4"]:before {
  content: "Y";
  visibility: visible;
  font-size: 14pt /* add new font-size for Y */
}

label[title="4"]>input {
  visibility: visible /* child element input's visibility */
}
```

```html
<label title="4" for="button-rating-2-5">
    4
    <input id="button-rating-2-5" type="radio" name="question-2" value="5" style="">
</label>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to comment, excuse my ignorance I don't understand the #changeLabel and how I am to include the id="changeLabel" part. I can only upload a CSS file, do I replace #changeLabel with the items I am referring to?? Thanks

Comment: Sorry for adding html. You can do this by using css code without changing the html code *(no ID required)*. I've edited snippet now.

Comment: Don't be sorry you are helping me, with the code above it still removed the button but then i added the below code which worked. label thanks heaps,          
    #button-rating-14-5 {
 visibility: visible;
 font-size: 14pt
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```css
#changeLabel{ font-size: 0; }
#changeLabel:before { content: "Y"; font-size: 14px; }
```

```html
<label title="4" for="button-rating-2-5" id="changeLabel">
    4
    <input id="button-rating-2-5" type="radio" name="question-2" value="5" style="">
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but it didn't seem to do anything, i have added in the question what else I have tried. I can insert the "y" now but cannot remove the old label without also removing the button